# NameNotFoundException while opening connection from Datasource, JNDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi

i had an application working with JSF and i oppened the connection manually, but now i have to change it and open all the connections from a Datasource, so i have an .xml file in the directory  (Jboss 7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
    <datasource
        jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyForum"
        enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true"
        pool-name="MyForum">
            <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</connection-url>
            <driver>hsqldb.jar</driver>
            <pool></pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password></password>
            </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Then i have the code to acces the JNDI name in a class "JdbcHelper"

```
public Connection createConnection() {

    try {
        String jndiKey = getProperty("JNDI_DATASOURCE");

        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndiKey);
        return ds.getConnection();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't open JDBC conection from JNDI", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't open JDBC conection", e);
    }
}
```

The line which is launching the exception is this one `DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndiKey);` I don't know if you need more information, but if you need just ask, i really need to do this and I can't find the solution :(

Update, here's the detail-message of the exception

```
datasources/MyForum -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MyForum
```

Thank you so much in advance. :)

Comment: Check that your JBoss server is starting without warning/error. Then, debbug your application and check that the value of `jndiKey` is `java:jboss/datasources/MyForum`.

Comment: Alredy did, and yes, the value seems to be correct. i've updated the detailed message of the exception, maybe that helps you to see what's wrong. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not initializing the `InitialContext` properly,
maybe that will help you: [Creating initial Context in JBoss AS 7.1.1](https://community.jboss.org/thread/200327)

Comment: That's what I thought, because when I debbuged it I saw so many "nulls". Now i'm habing a lunch, I'll check it later :D Thank you!! :3